# Vue: Backcolor doesn't change

Tags: node.js, vue-material

I'm trying to use Vue-Material for the first time and when I tried to change the background color on the default theme, it simply does not change the color and the background color always turns white. I'm doing the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'

import App from './App'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)

Vue.material.registerTheme({
  default: {
    primary: 'red',
    accent: 'red',
    background: {
      color: 'blue-grey',
      hue: 800
    }
  },
  green: {
    primary: 'green',
    accent: 'pink'
  },
  orange: {
    primary: 'orange',
    accent: 'green'
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

I've tried that too, as shown in Vue-Material documentation:

```
Vue.material.registerTheme('default', {
    primary: 'blue',
    accent: 'red',
    warn: 'orange',
    background: {
        color: 'blue-grey',
        hue: 800
    }
})
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you please add your codepen ?

Comment: please check issue https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/355

Comment: I have added codepen to here with demo https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/RZMQVB

Comment: I've edited my question and it includes your code, but it did not work ... I'm just creating a new Vue-Material project without changing anything except the Theme as it's in the Vue-material documentation. Then I tried to do as you pointed out, but the backcolor remains white.